# Code highlighting and image placement breaks despite correct syntax

Tags: support, bug, design, markdown, code-formatting

[*Signal Processing* answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87933/50076), normal vs preview:

[image]

It's only toward the bottom of the post, yet it doesn't happen toward bottom of a [much longer post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78515/50076). I confirmed it's also reproduced only with the offending bit, pasted below.

Reproduced in Firefox, Edge, Chrome, Windows 10, Windows 11. Reproduced on *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)* by pasting and submitting an edit temporarily.

---

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwa3Q.png" width="330">



`fft(x)[0]` is the plot summed. Note the primary signal here is obliterated by the window's excellent frequency resolution, and what remains is leakage. The image shows the `'constant'` case, with DC zeroed; its removal matters because `fft(win)` effectively behaves like `[1, -1, 1, -1]`, so every non-zero input makes a huge difference. Yet, removal of any bin adjacent to DC would have a nearly identical effect.

This explains the behavior in terms of DFT and resolves the apparent "paradox". I don't think it's possible, however, to do this for more than just one case at a time and prove dependencies on $\tau$ as we have. Sometimes the DFT has a DC, other times not, and adjacent bins also vary. It's what motivated my closed form solution.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug. The backend rendering is not compliant with CommonMark. Given that it appears associated with raw HTML `<img>` tags, it's likely that there's something happening when Stack Exchange runs the process to strip disallowed HTML.

#### Workaround

Several of your blank lines have a single space character on them. While that *should* have no consequence, you can work around this issue by removing the space characters on the blank lines.

#### Reduced example

##### CommonMark

The test [Markdown with spaces on some blank lines renders correctly on CommonMark's test site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=A%20paragraph%0A%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%22%3E%0A%0Aparagraph%20%232%2C%20which%20should%20be%20separate%2C%20%60has%20some%20code%60.%0A%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%22%3E%0A%0Aparagraph%20%233%2C%20which%20should%20be%20separate%2C%20%60has%20some%20code%60.%0A%0Aparagraph%20%234%2C%20which%20should%20be%20separate%2C%20%60has%20some%20code%60.%0A).

##### Markdown

```markdown
A paragraph

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">
 
paragraph #2, which should be separate, `has some code`.
  
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">
 
paragraph #3, which should be separate, `has some code`.

paragraph #4, which should be separate, `has some code`.
```

##### Rendered by Stack Exchange (flawed)

A paragraph

[image]
 
paragraph #2, which should be separate, `has some code`.
  
[image]
 
paragraph #3, which should be separate, `has some code`.

paragraph #4, which should be separate, `has some code`.

#### Using workaround of not having a space character on blank lines (renders correctly)

##### CommonMark

[Rendering the workaround on CommonMark's test site](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=A%20paragraph%0A%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%22%3E%0A%0Aparagraph%20%232%2C%20which%20should%20be%20separate%2C%20%60has%20some%20code%60.%0A%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwRMuO.png%22%3E%0A%0Aparagraph%20%233%2C%20which%20should%20be%20separate%2C%20%60has%20some%20code%60.%0A%0Aparagraph%20%234%2C%20which%20should%20be%20separate%2C%20%60has%20some%20code%60.%0A): also renders correctly

##### Markdown

```markdown
A paragraph

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">

paragraph #2, which should be separate, `has some code`.

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png">

paragraph #3, which should be separate, `has some code`.

paragraph #4, which should be separate, `has some code`.
```

##### Rendered by Stack Exchange (correct)

A paragraph

[image]

paragraph #2, which should be separate, `has some code`.

[image]

paragraph #3, which should be separate, `has some code`.

paragraph #4, which should be separate, `has some code`.

#### Image credit

The image used is:

- [Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png) `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png`
  original URL: http://www.iconarchive.com/show/weathy-icons-by-icojam/24-tornado-icon.html
  Artist: Icojam
  Iconset: Weathy Icons (25 icons)
  License: Public Domain

Comment: I saw the space and wanted to test ridding of it at last minute, but lazied out. I think something similar happens with Sphinx docs in Python - what's with all these sophisticated programs botching up `'\n'.join(l.strip() for l in txt.split('\n') if l.strip() == '')`?? _(rhetorical q)_